# I'm trying to use CotentDialog to get some data and change it in my database in UWP XAML but I encountered some issues

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

```
private async void iconu_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (BigGrid.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        ContentDialog dialog2 = new ContentDialog
        {
            Title = "Please select a Grid!",
            Content = "When selected it will have a border :)",
            CloseButtonText = "Cancel",
        };
        ContentDialogResult result2 = await dialog2.ShowAsync();
        return;
    }
    ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog
    {   

        Title = "Please enter your information",
        CloseButtonText = "Cancel",
        PrimaryButtonText = "OK",
        Content = new StackPanel
        {
            Children =
        {
            new TextBlock { Text = "Title:" },
            new TextBox { Name = "TitleTextBox" },
            new TextBlock { Text = "Description:" },
            new TextBox { Name = "DescriptionTextBox" },
            new TextBlock { Text = "Select Date:" },
            new DatePicker { Name = "DatePicker" },
            new TextBlock { Text = "Select Time:" },
            new TimePicker { Name = "TimePicker" }
        }
        }
    };

    ContentDialogResult result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
    if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
        {
            TextBox titleTextBox = dialog.FindName("TitleTextBox") as TextBox;
            TextBox descriptionTextBox = dialog.FindName("DescriptionTextBox") as TextBox;
            DatePicker datePicker = dialog.FindName("DatePicker") as DatePicker;
            TimePicker timePicker = dialog.FindName("TimePicker") as TimePicker;

            if (titleTextBox != null && descriptionTextBox != null && datePicker != null && timePicker != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("All controls are not null.");
                string title = titleTextBox.Text;
                string description = descriptionTextBox.Text;
                DateTime selectedDateTime = datePicker.Date.DateTime.Date + timePicker.Time;
                Debug.WriteLine($"1.TitleTextBox: {titleTextBox.Text}, DescriptionTextBox: {descriptionTextBox.Text}, DatePicker: {datePicker.Date}, TimePicker: {timePicker.Time}");

            int Id = ((Note)BigGrid.SelectedItem).Id;
                Notedatabase.UpdateData(Id, title, description, selectedDateTime);
                BigGrid.ItemsSource = Notedatabase.GetData();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Some controls are null.");
                Debug.WriteLine($"2.TitleTextBox: {titleTextBox}, DescriptionTextBox: {descriptionTextBox}, DatePicker: {datePicker}, TimePicker: {timePicker}");
                ContentDialog dialog1 = new ContentDialog
                {
                    Title = "Please input All values!",
                    Content = "Thank you :)", 
                    CloseButtonText = "Cancel",
                };
                await dialog1.ShowAsync();
            }
    }
```

I am getting data from a Locally saved Database, BigGrid is a GridView.ItemTemplate

I expected to get the values to save but it kept throwing the other dialog box "Please input All values"

```
Debug.WriteLine($"2.TitleTextBox: {titleTextBox}, DescriptionTextBox: {descriptionTextBox}, DatePicker: {datePicker}, TimePicker: {timePicker}");
```

This line shows that there is nothing inside

I think I did this wrongly? But I'm not too sure

```
TextBox titleTextBox = dialog.FindName("TitleTextBox") as TextBox;
            TextBox descriptionTextBox = dialog.FindName("DescriptionTextBox") as TextBox;
            DatePicker datePicker = dialog.FindName("DatePicker") as DatePicker;
            TimePicker timePicker = dialog.FindName("TimePicker") as TimePicker;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

```
            StackPanel stackPanel = (StackPanel)dialog.Content;
            string title = ((TextBox)stackPanel.Children[1]).Text;
            string description = ((TextBox)stackPanel.Children[3]).Text;
            DateTime selectedDate = ((DatePicker)stackPanel.Children[5]).Date.DateTime;
            TimeSpan selectedTime = ((TimePicker)stackPanel.Children[7]).SelectedTime.Value;
```

I used this instead and it worked :)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**